# 1013. Partition Array Into Three Parts With Equal Sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, python-itertools

I am working on Leetcode problem 1013. I found the solution that just one line, but I can not understand the conception behind the code.

```
import itertools
A = [0,2,1,-6,6,-7,9,1,2,0,1]
def canThreePartsEqualSum(A):
    return (lambda x,y: x in y and 2*x in y and 3*x in y)(sum(A)//3,itertools.accumulate(A))
print(canThreePartsEqualSum(A))
```

hope some of you can describe it detailedly for me, thanks ><

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to break down each part of this

**sum(A)** = 9

**sum(A)//3** = 9//3 = 3 (This is floor division)

**itertools.accumulate(A)**  -
returns an accumulative total of the passed iterable
In this case, it would be [0, 2, 3, -3, 3, -4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 9]

**(sum(A)//3,itertools.accumulate(A))** - this is a tuple.
It is effectively (3, [0, 2, 3, -3, 3, -4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 9])
but if you tried to print this it would just give you (3, <itertools.accumulate object>)

**`(lambda x,y: x in y and 2*x in y and 3*x in y)`** - This is a lambda function and it can be rather confusing to look at for beginners, it is basically an anonymous function.
In this case, it is checking if `x` (which is the first element in the tuple`(sum(A)//3,itertools.accumulate(A))` so in this case it's a 3) is in the accumulate object and whether `2*3` and `3*3` is also in that list.

If all conditions are met it will return True, otherwise False.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. But I still have another question that, you say if I print (sum(A)//3,itertools.accumulate(A)) it would be show as (3, <itertools.accumulate object at 0x00000295FC0BB380>), why? then I use print(list(itertools.accumulate(A))), it is good. What is the conception behind the code?

Comment: Because it is a generator and yields when needed. When you call list() it runs the generator and returns the result as a list.

Comment: @LeeeJeff if this has answered your question please don't forget to mark it as the answer and upvote :)